# Term or phrase similar to ghost town but without remaining structures

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm a local historian and I was wondering what the term might be for former railroad communities/mill towns with no remaining structures? I realize ghost town is the wrong term because they have no remaining buildings or architecture. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does "with no remaining structures" mean there is nothing above ground to show that the town was there or does it mean that there are simply no structures related to the railroad/mill remaining but other buildings still exist?

Comment: The remains of a former town/the footprint of a former town/the ruins of a former town.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_Mills,_California), for example, is referred to as a ghost town. Is it like that? Do you even need a specific word? *The once-bustling mill town is reduced to artifacts scattered amongst the tumbleweeds...*

Comment: Would "ruins" do?

Comment: *Former settlement* seems a common term in archaeology for a town/village/etc that is no longer there, or *site of former settlement* to emphasise the location. Not very exciting, but [example 1](https://highland.esdm.co.uk/Monument/MHG52910), [example 2](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/humanities/departments/classics-and-archaeology/research/research-projects/past-projects/flixborough.aspx)

Comment: _Historical site_ or _heritage site_ are two more ideas, if the location has some significance.

Comment: `vanished town`  ,  `long gone/ bygone city` , `perished town`?   Though   `former settlement` mentioned above seems most appropriate to me, even if it comes with the word settlement instead of town.

Comment: haunted ground, historical ground

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering what the term might be for former railroad communities/mill towns with no remaining structures?

They are usually known as "**the site of** the/a **former** [noun phrase]"

[Archaeological investigations at the site of the former Capitol Cinema, Tonbridge, Kent](https://www.mola.org.uk/archaeological-investigations-site-former-capitol-cinema-tonbridge-kent-kent-archaeol-soc-earchaeolo),

[The Site of the Former St Loye's College, Topsham Road, Exeter.](https://archaeologydataservice.ac.uk/archives/view/exeterstloyes_ecc_2021/index.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

I've read conflicting definitions for 'ghost town' including locations with *or* without extant structures. The general definition I find useful is a location rendered uninhabitable or abandoned through a lack of economic viability, or by natural- or human-made disasters.

• Lack of economic viability can define the ghost towns found in the American West, primarily old mining ghost towns where the mines played out, or where the railroads did not reach.

• Natural disaster ghost towns can be exemplified by Pompeii (a rather extreme example) or a more contemporary example of the former capital city of Plymouth, Monserrat, also rendered uninhabitable by volcanic activity.

• Human-caused radioactive contamination disasters are exemplified by the Chernobyl reactor explosion which rendered the cities of Chernobyl and  Pripyat, Ukraine, uninhabitable, or the area around the Fukushima Daiichi reactor in Japan which was the result of an earthquake and tsunami - a natural- and human-made disaster in one event.

• Human caused chemical contamination, from asbestos mining in Wittenoom, Western Australia to zinc and lead environmental damage from mining are more prevalent, but contamination from ammunition dumps and unexploded ordnance, as exemplified by the town of Tynham, Dorset in the UK can be considered as well.

Although referring to Wikipedia as a sole source is frowned upon, the page on the concept of the Ghost town has many more examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_town

I did non-Wikipedia research on some of the locales mentioned, and I could find no discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

How about "lost town"?

[A recent American news article](https://www.denver7.com/news/national/efforts-underway-to-honor-first-us-town-run-by-formerly-enslaved-people) describes the site of the former town of Mitchelville (the first town in America to be run by people who were formerly enslaved) as "the lost town":

> The Mitchelville Freedom Park is comprised of a collection of historical artifacts and replicas that tell the story of **the lost town**.

From the following, it's clear that they have no remaining buildings or architecture there:

> "They set up this settlement and now **there's not much real trace of it left**. And so, this whole effort to hang on to that history, to reveal it once again, I think is pretty amazing."

If the place used to be a city, the term "[lost city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_City)" might work too.

> In the popular imagination, a lost city is a real, once-prosperous and well-populated area of human habitation that fell into terminal decline and whose location was later forgotten.